# Theming a field in Drupal-6

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-themes

I have a custom content (using cck) namely thewittyshit and it has a field namely field_thewittyshit . I want to theme field_thewittyshit field for all the views. I wrote the following code and saved it in a new file namely views-view-field--default--field-thewittyshit-value.tpl.php . But still no change is reflected in any of my views or node display.

```
<?php
// $Id: views-view-field.tpl.php,v 1.1 2008/05/16 22:22:32 merlinofchaos Exp $
/**
* This template is used to print a single field in a view. It is not
* actually used in default Views, as this is registered as a theme
* function which has better performance. For single overrides, the
* template is perfectly okay.
*
* Variables available:
* - $view: The view object
* - $field: The field handler object that can process the input
* - $row: The raw SQL result that can be used
* - $output: The processed output that will normally be used.
*
* When fetching output from the $row, this construct should be used:
* $data = $row->{$field->field_alias}
*
* The above will guarantee that you'll always get the correct data,
* regardless of any changes in the aliasing that might happen if
* the view is modified.
*/
?>
<em>
<?php print $output; ?>
<em/>
```

I want to format the text. In this code i am just making it appear in italics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template you are overriding must reside in your theme directory. Find the `views-view-field.tpl.php` file in the views module folder and copy and paste it into your theme directory where your `views-view-field--default--field-thewittyshit-value.tpl.php` resides. This should let you then use this file. Also make sure to clear the cache after you do this.

For debugging purposes, if you are still having troubles, make sure views is using `views-view-field--default--field-thewittyshit-value.tpl.php`. Click on "information" next to the theme option in the views UI under the "Basic settings" section. The theme that you are using will be in bold.